# What would keep a Microsoft Word AutoNew() macro from running?

Tags: microsoft-word, templates, vba

I'm using Microsoft Office 2003 and creating a bunch of template documents to standardize some tasks.

I know it's standard practice to put the templates in an certain place Office expects to find them but that won't work for me.  What I want is to have  "My Template Foo.dot" and "My Template Bar.dot", etc. in the "My Foo Bar Stuff" on a shared drive and users will double click on the template to create a new Foo or Bar.

What's I'd really like is for the user to double click on the Foo template and be prompted for a couple of items related to their task (e.g., a project number) and have a script in the template change the name that Save will default to something like "Foo for Project 1234.doc".

I asked on [Google Groups](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.word.vba.general/browse_thread/thread/d52848f3e43af032?lnk=igtc&fwc=1) and got an answer that worked....for a while.  Then my AutoNew macro stopped kicking in when I created a new document by double clicking on the template.  I have no idea why or how to debug it.

I'm a software engineering with 25+ years of experience but a complete Office automation noob.  Specific solutions and pointers to "this is how to automate Word" FAQs are welcome.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Changing macro security to simply not run macros (rather than always running, or prompting the user) would do this.
Tools > Macros > Security: High or Very High could be killing yours off

When you get your new document, can you run the macro by hand? (I don't mean as a workaround, just as a test to see if they are disabled or if something else is failing)

Not sure why you can't put these in an "expected location". If you put them on a file share you can easily point Word at that location for Workgroup templates without affecting locally stored templates.
When a user goes to File > New they get all their local templates, plus any in the Workgroup templates folder. Each folder from those two places appears as a tab (automagically) and if both location have a folder of the same name their contents are merged. If a template of the same name appears in a matching folder in both, the local version is shown.

To change workgroup templates location go to Tools > options > file location. Give it a full path, ideally UNC rather than share. You can enable this folder for offline use in the usual way (ie browse to it and right click > make available offline).

You can use Group Policy to set this location if you prefer.

Ideally give most users read-only access to this folder, not modify.

Heope this helps